# EntityFrameworkCore 2.x and PrivateAsset="All"

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm building an `.NetCoreApp1.1` webapi.  We have the typical business and data layer assemblies broken out. When we added `EntityFrameworkCore 2.x` to the data access project, I was able to test functionality that went across projects.  But the webapi stopped working! We were no longer able to start the app. program.cs-main failed with the exception:

> *System.MissingMethodException: "Method not found: 'System.IServiceProvider >MicrosoftExtensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtens>ions.BuildServiceProvider...'*

Articles indicated a package type mismatch but I couldn't find anything out of place.  The `EntityFrameworkcore` in the data layer was suspect since it was version 2.0.0-preview1-final.  In `VS2017` there is a new feature to mark packages as private to the assembly. This made sense to do this with EF in the data layer so I opened the project and marked them PrivateAsset="All"

```
   <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.0.0-preview1-final" **PrivateAssets="All"** />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.0.0-preview1-final" PrivateAssets="All" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.0.0-preview1-final" PrivateAssets="All" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="2.0.0-preview1-final" PrivateAssets="All" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.0-preview1-final" PrivateAssets="All" />
      <PackageReference Include="WindowsAzure.Storage" Version="8.1.4" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

This solved my problem. I was able to rebuild and run the webapi application.  **But**, now my test failed with:

> *Message: Test method 
>   ACMEAppTests.AppTests_FileManagerSave.FileManager_SaveFile threw exception: >System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.*

This makes no sense.  The assembly is there.  So it seems I can't get both applications working at the same time.  The errors make no sense to me.  There seems to be little information on the PrivateAsset="All" feature for packages.  I found this description:

*Tip
A private package reference (PrivateAssets="All") means this dependency is local to the current project. For example, if Project A has a build only dependency and Project B depends on A, dotnet restore will not add A's build-only dependencies into Project B.*

reference 
[.Net Command Line Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet#installation)

How to resolve this?  Figure out why the webapi stopped working (Method not found) or debug the missing assembly reference that isn't, from what I can tell, missing?

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix ASP.NET Core 1.1 with EF Core 2.0. They share some common dependencies (e.g. Logging, DependencyInjection, etc.) which means all your Microsoft.* package versions need to more-or-less align.

See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#controlling-dependency-assets) about PrivateAssets. Adding `PrivateAssets="All"` prevents your data layer's dependencies from propagating into your app. Hence, you get *could not load assembly* errors.